# JUnit 5 a very simple test keeps resolving on Undefined

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit5

How is this possible Thanks for your help

I am on Intellij Community 2022 and I cant believe this Assert is failing.

Assert.assertTrue(new String("ss").equals("ss")) -- this fails
Assert.assertTrue(new String("ss").matches("ss")) -- this fails

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## `Assertions`, not `Assert`

No `Assert` class in JUnit Jupiter.

Use [`Assertions`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) class.

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue( new String( "ss" ).equals( "ss" ) );
```

> Tests passed: 1 of 1

For less typing, use static import.

```java
package work.basil.example.squarematrix;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class SquareMatrixTest
{
    @Test
    void report ( )
    {
        assertTrue( new String( "ss" ).equals( "ss" ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For compare to String expressions you have to use assertEqual function.
Usage:

```
assertEqual(String1, String2);
```